# C/C++ - Find Makefile file path programmably

Tags: c++, c, shell, makefile

I'm trying to read an " **Makefile** "  in C/C++

it works by doing: `system("make -C /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder flash");`

" **make flash** " is the command to run the file and **/Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder** is the

file path. This code works, but how can i make the file path locally, to read from the same

debug folder ( where the program is ) without writing it manually ?

Comment: What do you mean be *reading the file* - you seem to be running it.

Comment: Sorry typo, but i want to point to the makefile in the same folder, without writing this long manually file path

Comment: Are you asking, “how can I run make from the current directory, where my program is running?” Wouldn't that just be, to omit the `-C /path/here` bit?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to have to specify the file at all? i.e. you just want to do system("make")? Or do you just not want to have to specify the path?

Comment: BRPocock, Yes, that what i'm asking, but it says now: make: *** /path/here: No such file or directory.  Stop.

Comment: I think he wants the C program to set the path so `make` doesn't use absolute paths for everything like it does with `-C`.

Comment: @user1104856: Protip: When BRPocock said `/path/here`, *it was not meant to mean that literal path.*

Comment: -1: I see much confusion in the answers due to ambiguity in the question. Some information, e.g. a stub of the Makefile and a typical invocation, would be of much help to the answerers. Please give all used paths precisely: where is the program? what is the current working directory of the program? what is the Makefile directory? with which paths does it work? with which does it fail?

Comment: At this point I cannot comprehend what the questioner wants. A translator is likely necessary; there is evidence of a weak grasp of both English (obviously not their primary language) and common documentation conventions. Sorry, I'm done with this one.

Comment: I didn't really understand this question either, but I feel like this may be something you could use a link to do, i.e. ln -s /path/to/Makefile Makefile, which would make a symbolic link to the target Makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the `int chdir(const char *path);` function. Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

/* ... */

chdir("/Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder");
system("make flash");
```

There's a lot of other useful functions in `<unistd.h>`, which should be present on any POSIX-based system. [Check here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) for the big list.

**EDIT:** If the path isn't constant, you'll probably want to provide it as a command line argument to your program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* ... */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <path>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    chdir(argv[1]);
    system("make flash");

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Run it with a line like `./foo /Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder`.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, unless someone sees a reason why not, I will delete mine in 5 minutes.

Comment: My code also works, but how can I run make from the current directory, where my program is running

Comment: Please explain why you want `make` running in two directories at once: the one that your program is in and `/Users/MyNAME/Desktop/Folder`.

Comment: I don't want to write  /Users/MyNAME/Desktop, becouse not every pc have the same system..

Comment: @user1104856 You can't if the target is in a different directory. That is why the make command accepts optional arguments.

Comment: Then that path should be provided as a parameter to your program.

Comment: @user1104856 Then you will have to take an argument for your program where the user can specify the location of the document.

Comment: @ Mike DeSimone please give me example

Comment: He just did. Are you talking about how to parse your main(int argc, int** argv) arguments?

Comment: No, your exampel is the best, but system is doing nothing, how to run?

Comment: +1, I like this solution though I probably wouldn't use `chdir()` but rather pass the path to `make` using the `-C` option like he was doing before.

Comment: I want to get current executable's file path without the executable name at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getcwd()` to get the current working directory:

```
char cmd[1040];
char cwd[1024];
if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
{
   snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s\" flash", cwd);
   system(cmd);
}
```

Comment: It says make: *** No rule to make target `flash'.  Stop.

Comment: I want to get current executable's file path without the executable name at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Um, leave out the path there?

```
make flash
```

will do the make and make will look in the current working directory.

Comment: It says : make: *** No rule to make target `flash'.  Stop.